# Number : calculate percentage using two cells

Tags: numbers

I can't believe I ask that but my brain seems offline this morning

I have two column (D1 (Day units) / E1 (Night units)

I want to create a new column with the percentage of use between day/night (with is D1/E1), with day first percentage displayed then night second percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage of D1 out of total units is `D1/SUM(D1:E1)`. Replace with E1 for night units.

[image]

[image]